# AS3 Application fades out while running

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a game in AS3 for Android. For some reason when I'm testing it on an Android device, after, lets say, 3 or 4 seconds, the screens starts to fade out till it's completely black while app is still running.

I have the "Stay Active/Awake" on "Android Developers Option".

I'm hoping you can help me with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Question Solved! Mods can remove or lock topic. 
Solution was https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1135401?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Then please create an answer here yourself as well, listing the central points from the link you found. Afterwards mark your own answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using only Accelerometer it doesn't count as a feature to stay awake. We have to force Android to stay awake by code. Basically when app is running it triggers stayAwake mode else it triggers normal mode.